# jQuery - When i formatted date then date goes to invalid date

Tags: jquery, date

how to format date. i want date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy 29/03/2016. when in am change night then checkout out date should be show after adding night but there is showing invalid date. 


**Html Code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-shield"></i>Check In</label><input type="text" id="checkin" class="HotelSearchFrom-Checkin" name="checkin" required/>
<select id="ddlnight" class="HotelSearchFrom-ddlNight">
<option value="0">Night</option>
<option value="1">1 Night</option>
<option value="2">2 Nights</option>
</select>
<label id="icon" for="name"><i class="icon-user"></i>Check Out</label>
<input type="text" id="checkout" class="HotelSearchFrom-Date" name="checkout" required/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

---

**jQuery Code**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#checkin,#checkout" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    (function($, window, document, undefined){
        $("#ddlnight").on("change", function(){
            var date = new Date($("#checkin").val());
            days = parseInt($("#ddlnight").val(), 10);
            if(!isNaN(date.getTime())){ 
                alert("if is working"); 
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
                $("#checkout").val(date.toInputFormat());
            } 
            else {
                alert("Invalid Date");  
            }
        });
        Date.prototype.toInputFormat = function() {
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
        var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
        return  (  (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + "/" + mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "/" +yyyy; // padding
        };
    })(jQuery, this, document);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with your opening and closing brackets. use this syntax and it must work fine. **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/aud6kL7s/)** of your core logic.

`(dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]) + "/" + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "/" + yyyy;`

What you previously had this part of code 
`((dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]) + "/" + mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0])`(you can notice the mistake with the braces) was giving a output of only the month . Honestly I am not sure why this happens. But wrapping up the ternary code inside the braces must fix your issue.

Comment: not woking i tried. when i alert checkin date then i it is showing invalid date

Comment: Can you check the fiddle link which I provided. See what is different in your code and in my code. may be we can find out something there

Comment: Also I see you are using date format of "dd/mm/yyyy" the machine which is running this code must also have the same format else you are in trouble.

Comment: @AjayKumar its working fine the link right? or is there any problem there?

Comment: which browser are using see in chrome

Comment: `when i alert checkin date then i it is showing invalid date` this is because you are creating a `Date` object which will have all the components like date time seconds UTC etc.. If you want to show proper date then you must explicitly take the day, month year from the date object and concat and show similar to what you are doing inside the `toInputFormat`

Comment: I am using **Moment.js**.but it is showing "[object Object]".
var datesd = $("#checkin").val( moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') );
$("#nicheckout").val(datesd);
[object Object]

Comment: That means the you are getting a Date object and not just a string. Place a debugger and see the values in that variable you can notice it's an object